# Issue with turning Wikipedia url string into URL in Swift

Tags: swift, url, wikipedia

The URL I am making is valid and will return the desired JSON when testing on Chrome, but fails in my project.

```
func createWikipediaURL(place: String) -> URL? {
    let _place = place.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
    let urlStr =
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts|pageimages&exintro&explaintext&generator=search&gsrsearch=intitle:\(_place)&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1"

    if let url = URL(string:urlStr) {
        return url
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

With the parameter "Malibu Beach" the function will create the proper URL, [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts|pageimages&exintro&explaintext&generator=search&gsrsearch=intitle:Malibu%20Beach&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages&exintro&explaintext&generator=search&gsrsearch=intitle:Malibu%20Beach&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1), but will also result in no URL being returned because this string cannot be casted into a URL. Any suggestions on how to make the string into a URL?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the `|` character in `urlStr`. I would suggest using Strings `addingPercentEncoding` method to make the string url safe. Doing so will mean that you won't need to manually replace spaces for `place` too.

```
func createWikipediaURL(place: String) -> URL? {
    let urlStr = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts|pageimages&exintro&explaintext&generator=search&gsrsearch=intitle:\(place)&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1"

    // Replaces special characters with their percent encoded counter-parts.
    guard let escapedUrlStr = urlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else { return nil }

    // There's no need for an if statement; URL can be returned as-is.
    return URL(string:escapedUrlStr)
}
```

Comment: Had the same exact problem. Thanks!